# Как из функции вернуть несколько data frame или по другому обойти ограничение на возврат одного результата в R?

Tags: сортировка, r

Есть несколько фреймов

```
a <- c(1:4)
a <- as.data.table(a)
a[[1]] <- c(a:d)
a[[2]] <- c(15,20,30,35)

b <- c(1:4)
b <- as.data.table(b)
b[[1]] <- c(1:4)
b[[2]] <- c(15,30,35,20)
```

Хочу написать функцию, которая принимает список фреймов с названием фреймов (они всегда разные и их много)

```
s <- c("a","b")
```

и сортирует их одинаковым образом

```
baseSort(s,2,"d")
        
baseSort = function(list,indexColumn,sortType="a") { 
SortTableName <- list[1]
    .
    код 
    .
}
```

Функция сортирует первый указанный фрейм по возрастанию или убыванию по одному из столбцов indexColumn = 2...n из первого фрейма в list.
Где n - количество столбцов фрейма.

Первый столбец во всех фреймах одинаковый. Все указанные в list фреймы от 2-го и далее сортируются по первому столбцу в том-же порядке, что и первый столбец первого фрейма после сортировки по возрастанию или убыванию в предыдущем шаге.

Как вернуть результат из функции? Оптимально было бы отсортировать прям из функции a и b в globalenv() также, как они отсортированы внутри функции.

но ни

```
get(SortTableName) <- array1
```

ни

```
assign(get(SortTableName),array1)
```

не работают.

Нужно рабочее решение для R-3.5.2

Comment: если ваша проблема состоит только в том, чтобы вернуть несколько результатов, то датафреймы можно обернуть в лист внутри функции и вернуть лист. можно еще почитать про оператор ```%<-%``` из пакета ```zeallot```.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Делаю `result <- lapply(1:TablesCount, function(i) get(paste0("array",i)))
     return(result)` всё работает. В документации прописано, что разбить можно так `c(a,b)  %<-% lapply(sorted,head)` и это тоже работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вытащить весь масиив из sorted, а не только head()? Есть решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Справился так:
внутри функции распихал все фреймы из list по массивам

```
TablesCount <- length(list)
for (array in 1:TablesCount) {
          
          assign(paste0("array",array),get_array(list[array]))
}
```

отсортированные фреймы схлопнул в один так, как нужно пакету `zeallot`:

```
 result <- lapply(1:TablesCount, function(i) get(paste0("array",i)))
 return(result)
```

Спасибо [rg4s](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/388388/rg4s) за подсказку.
Вызываю функцию так, как прописано в документации по пакету:

```
c(a,b,c)  %<-% lapply(baseSort(s,2,"a"),head,n=6)
```

Решение работает.

Очень хочется теперь избавится от лишнего параметра n=6 (сколько строк выдавать) и от выдачи через head(), но как это сделать непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Любое количество таблиц можно отсорировать по одному и тому же столбцу, например, так:

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(a = c(2, 3, 1, 4), b = 1:4)
b <- copy(a)
ab <- list(a, b)
lapply(ab, function(x) setorder(x, a))
ab
```

Comment: Мне нужно от 2 до m разных data frame, отсортированных одинаково. Сливать их в один противоречит условиям моей задачи.

Comment: Вам бы код запустить и посмотреть на результат.

Comment: Код я запускал, получется лист сцепленных массивов ab, который надо еще в цикле разлепить на массивы a и b. Я же четко написал в задаче, что нужна функция, сортирующая каждый фрейм отдельно. Должен получиться отсортированный фрейм а и отсортированный так-же фрейм b после запуска функции baseSort(). И я не спрашивал, как мне отсортировать, я спрашивал, как несколько результатов вернуть или обойти это ограничение.

Comment: `Все указанные в list фреймы` и у меня фреймы в листе.

Comment: в list у меня названия фреймов, а не сами фреймы. `s <- c("a","b")`